# Copy the contents of CStringArray to std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, mfc

As the question states I would like to copy the contents of a `CStringArray` into a `std::vector<std::string>`.
Any suggestions?

Comment: i'm not familiar with mfc, but maybe something like `for(int i=0; i<cs.GetSize(); i++) vs.push_back((LPCTSTR)cs.ElementAt(i));`?

Comment: @itwasntpete: Inefficient: passing a string as `char*` means a `strlen` call is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#if defined(UNICODE) || defined(_UNICODE)
typedef std::wstring string;
#else
typedef std::string string;
#endif

typedef std::vector<string> StringVector;

void CmfcstrarDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{

    CStringArray strs;
    strs.Add(_T("one"));
    strs.Add(_T("two"));
    strs.Add(_T("three"));

    StringVector copy;

    for (int n = 0; n < strs.GetCount(); n++)
    {
        const CString& s = strs.GetAt(n);
        copy.push_back(string(s));
    }

    StringVector::const_iterator citer = copy.cbegin();
    for (; citer != copy.cend(); citer++)
    {
        OutputDebugString(citer->c_str());
        OutputDebugString(_T("\n"));
    }

}
```

Comment: It is wise to use bar.reserve, when you know how many elements are copied into the vector.

Comment: You can avoid that `#ifdef` : `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;`

Comment: @MSalters: I think STL strings don't play well with the `TCHAR` model (which to me is something obsolete from the "prehistory" of Win32 :) I would just abandon the `TCHAR` model, and assume Unicode builds, and `CString` as storing Unicode (UTF-16) strings. So, the OP should figure out if he wants UTF-8 in the `std::string`, or some other encoding, and use something like `CW2A` (or `CT2A`) to convert from `CString` to `std::string`.

Answer (score 6):

Because `CStringArray` is also allocated in a linear array, there is no need for a loop.
Simply use the insert function and define the start and the end element of the `CStringArray`!

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CStringArray array;
    array.Add(_T("Test1"));
    array.Add(_T("Test2"));
    array.Add(_T("Test3"));
    array.Add(_T("Test4"));
    
    vector<tstring> vec;
    vec.insert(vec.begin(), &array[0], &array[array.GetSize() - 1] + 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you are using the `TCHAR` model, you may want to use the `_T("...")` decoration for the the strings in your sample: `_T("Test1")`, `_T("Test2")`, etc.

Comment: Not really needed. the CString constructor takes char* and wchar_*. But you are right. I will change it.

Comment: Yes, probably in the `PCYSTR` constructor they call `MultiByteToWideChar()` or `WideCharToMultiByte()` for conversion. But it's a run-time waste, since it can be done at compile-time with a simple `_T("...")` decoration.

Answer (score 3):

`CStringArray` contains `CString`s. In Unicode builds (which have been the default since VS2005, and should be considered for modern C++ Windows software), `CString` stores **Unicode UTF-16** strings.

Instead, `std::vector<std::string>` contains `std::string`s, which can store ANSI or MBCS strings, or UTF-8 strings, but *not* Unicode UTF-16 strings.

So, to properly perform this conversion, you have to think first **how to convert from `CString` to `std::string`**.

An option could be to use the [**`CT2A`** conversion helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx) (or `CW2A`, if you consider only Unicode builds, and `CString` as storing always UTF-16 strings).

However, note that the conversion from Unicode (`CString`) to "ANSI" can be lossy. A non-lossy conversion could be from UTF-16 to UTF-8 (to convert from a Unicode UTF-16 to a Unicode UTF-8 string, it's possible to use `CW2A` with `CP_UTF8` conversion flag).

Anyway, assuming that the default conversion performed by `CT2A` is acceptable for you, you can consider simple code like the following: just iterate through the `CStringArray`, convert current `CString` to `std::string` using `CT2A`, and `push_back` the resulting string to the `std::vector`; note that thanks to C++11/14 move semantics, returning a `std::vector<std::string>` from the function is not a performance problem.

```
std::vector<std::string> CStringArrayToStdVector(const CStringArray& source)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    result.reserve(source.GetCount());

    for (INT_PTR i = 0; i < source.GetCount(); ++i)
    {
        result.push_back(std::string(CT2A(source.GetAt(i))));
    }

    return result;
}
```